# PHP Long Runing Process - respond back to caller, but continue with processing

Tags: php, apache, rest, pthreads

Hi All,

I have implemented a REST API in PHP to return data to another application upon request. Some requests can take 30 seconds, some take 2 minutes and others can take up to an hour. If the response takes longer than 2 minutes, l need to respond back to the calling application that l will be making a callback to the calling application, once the data extract completes.

The data request can be small or very large - dependent upon what the calling application requires.

I have Google'ed around and come across the pThreads implementation, but it says that it should NOT be used in an application hosted on a WebServer. [Amp](https://amphp.org/) looks like what l need, but l need the http response to terminate with the calling application, while the SQL continues to be generated - i.e. the http request to continue.

The other solution, that l want to avoid is to mark certain requests as long running - since some requests can take 30 seconds at certain times of the day, but exceed 2 mins at other points of the day.

The requirements are as follows:

- Accept the request - and run the SQL to extract the data
- If the SQL request is still running after 2 minutes, then respond back with a JSON response saying that l will use the call back mechanism. But the SQL request needs to continue, and the JSON data to be written to a flat file for the callback
- If the SQL request completes in less than 2 minutes, respond back with the JSON response with the data

The issue is that once the SQL Request is running, the program blocks until it completes. I need the SQL request to run in a separately, and monitor how long it is taking.

Can anybody provide some sample code, and framework/ library that can help with the above?

I would gratefully accept any help with the above.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to just always use the call back mechanism (web hook?), regardless of how long the request takes?

Comment: Hi, Yes - that would be easier, and may be what l do (tight deadlines) - but if not now - l would like to see whether there is another solution for this. My issue is lack of knowledge about the http request and responding back to it allowing the calling application to terminate, but for my php script to continue processing.